# How can we mark function parameters (string literals) as localisable?

Tags: swift, xcode, foundation

I'm writing a convenience init for `NSError`.

```
extension NSError {
    public convenience init(domain: String = #file, code: Int = Int(#line), localizedDescription: String) {
        self.init(domain: domain, code: code, userInfo: [NSLocalizedDescriptionKey: localizedDescription])
    }
}
```

To create an error with localised description from string literal I now can do:

```
let localisedError = NSError(localizedDescription: NSLocalizedString("Some description that will be localized.", comment: "Comment for translator"))
```

Is there a way to pass literals directly to `init` (or any other `func`) in a way that will ensure that they will be automatically passed to translations that Xcode generates as it does for literals passed to `NSLocalizedString()`.
So that I could just call

```
let localisedError = NSError(localizedDescription: "Some description that will be localized.")
```

Comment: Can't u change the last line of the extension to this? ```self.init(domain: domain, code: code, userInfo: [NSLocalizedDescriptionKey: NSLocalizedString(localizedDescription, comment: comment)])``` ?

Comment: If you rely on Xcode's Export Localizations feature or any generations tools that scans for string literals in the code then I don't think it's possible. These generation tools rely on string literals being passed directly to NSLocalizedString. Maybe it can be possible if Swift has the capability of defining literal values that can be used at compile time instead of runtime. I'm not sure if Swift macros or Swift package plugins can be used to achieve this.

Comment: @udi, I strongly doubt that reordering the code the way you propose would work – literals won't be extracted with Xcode generation tools.

Comment: @alobaili, in `SwiftUI` there is a type `LocalizedStringKey` that does what I need and comes with handy interpolation capabilities, but not sure if it is good to couple that UI related with UI independent `Foundation`.
Swift macros potentially could do the the job, but I'm not very familiar with them yet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you can just take a [`LocalizedStringResource`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/localizedstringresource). This is a Foundation type, and works correctly with string literals and string interpolations, just like `LocalizedStringKey` does.

```
public convenience init(domain: String = #file, code: Int = Int(#line), localizedDescription: LocalizedStringResource) {
    self.init(domain: domain, code: code, userInfo: [
        NSLocalizedDescriptionKey: String(localized: localizedDescription)
    ])
}
```

Comment: Very helpful suggestion! This is what I was looking for. Worth noticing that ' LocalizedStringResource` is @available from macOS 13, iOS 16.
It doesn't seem right for me to put localised string where the key for it is expected.
I would rather do: `NSLocalizedDescriptionKey: localizedDescription.key` and later somewhere: 
`extension NSError: LocalizedError {
    public var errorDescription: String? { String(localized: .init(localizedDescription)) }
}
`

Comment: @PaulB "It doesn't seem right for me to put localised string where the key for it is expected." Did you misunderstand what `NSLocalizedDescriptionKey` is? "Key" here is in the sense of "keys of a dictionary", not a localisation key. It's one of those confusing parts of Objective-C's naming convention :) The value corresponding to [`NSLocalizedDescriptionKey`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nslocalizeddescriptionkey) should be a localised description. It's what will be returned by `localizedDescription`.

Comment: I was just about to disavow my previous line. Indeed it was about keys of the `Dictionary'. After a bit of thought, I realised that a localised value must be passed for this dictionary key. It is not intended to be a key for the string to be localised. Not to mention that my suggestion would not work when using string interpolation: "Failed to authorise user \\(user)".
I have no option but to **gratefully accept** this answer.